# didSelectRowAt indexPath function is not working while search is active

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uialertview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to make a search and tap one of the cell to display AlertView. And this alertView asks to add to the array. I am using `didSelectRowAt indexPath` function and a searching function. Before any searching, everything works fine. But if searching is active, searchbar works fine but tapped cell does not display an alertView. I think something is wrong with `didSelectRowAt indexPath` function.

Here is my search function:

```
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        filteredData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        let textToSearch = searchController.searchBar.text!
        filteredData = mainArray.filter({($0.names?.lowercased().contains(textToSearch.lowercased()))!})
        listTableView.reloadData()
    }
    else {
        filteredData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And this is the didSelectRow Function:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Add To array?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
        if self.resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            self.secondArray.append(self.filteredData[indexPath.row])
        }
        else {
            self.secondArray.append(self.mainArray[indexPath.row])
        }
        print(self.secondArray)
    }
    let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
        print("Do not append")
    }
    alertController.addAction(yesAction)
    alertController.addAction(noAction)
    if self.presentedViewController == nil {
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And Here is `cellForRowAt` function. I know it seems complicated.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier: String = "BasicCell"
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableCell
    //Label1
    if resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        let item: LocationModel = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        let desenNoToString = item.DesenNo
        let desenString = "\(desenNoToString)"
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:"\"(.*)\"")
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: desenString, range:NSMakeRange(0,desenString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (desenString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label1!.text = result
        }
        //Label2
        let dolarToString = item.Dolar
        let dolarString = "\(dolarToString)"
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: dolarString, range:NSMakeRange(0,dolarString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (dolarString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label2!.text = result
        }
        //Label3
        let zeminToString = item.Zemin
        let zeminString = "\(zeminToString)"
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: zeminString, range:NSMakeRange(0,zeminString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (zeminString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label3!.text = result
        }
        //Label4
        let renkToString = item.Renk
        let renkString = "\(renkToString)"
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: renkString, range:NSMakeRange(0,renkString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (renkString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label4!.text = result
        }
        //Label5
        let enToString = item.En
        let enString = "\(enToString)"
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: enString, range:NSMakeRange(0,enString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (enString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label5!.text = result
        }
        //Label6
        let euroToString = item.Euro
        let euroString = "\(euroToString)"
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: euroString, range:NSMakeRange(0,euroString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (euroString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label6!.text = result
        }
    }else {
        let item: LocationModel = feedItems[indexPath.row]
        let desenNoToString = item.DesenNo
        let desenString = "\(desenNoToString)"
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:"\"(.*)\"")
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: desenString, range:NSMakeRange(0,desenString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (desenString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label1!.text = result
        }
        //Label2
        let dolarToString = item.Dolar
        let dolarString = "\(dolarToString)"
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: dolarString, range:NSMakeRange(0,dolarString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (dolarString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label2!.text = result
        }
        //Label3
        let zeminToString = item.Zemin
        let zeminString = "\(zeminToString)"
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: zeminString, range:NSMakeRange(0,zeminString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (zeminString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label3!.text = result
        }
        //Label4
        let renkToString = item.Renk
        let renkString = "\(renkToString)"
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: renkString, range:NSMakeRange(0,renkString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (renkString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label4!.text = result
        }
        //Label5
        let enToString = item.En
        let enString = "\(enToString)"
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: enString, range:NSMakeRange(0,enString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (enString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label5!.text = result
        }
        //Label6
        let euroToString = item.Euro
        let euroString = "\(euroToString)"
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(
            in: euroString, range:NSMakeRange(0,euroString.utf16.count)) {
            let result = (euroString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at:1))
            myCell.label6!.text = result
        }
    }
    return myCell
}
```

Hope You guys can help me.

Edit: Still have the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your cellForRowAt method look like?

Comment: I edited my question and added that method. Can you please Check it Again?

Answer (score 0):

At DidSelectRowAtIndexPath,

**Incorrect:**

```
if self.presentedViewController == nil {
   self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

**Just Replace with:**

```
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Description:** 
For normal scenario, When you tapped on any tableview cell at that time no controller was presented. So "self.presentedViewController == nil" always be true.

But, Whiles searching any value, UISearchbar Controller always be presented. So condition will always be false.

We can present alert view, even on presented controller. So not required to check such condition.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i think you are wrong. I did your suggestion, replaced it and i had warning **Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x102103e00>  which is already presenting (null)**.